# angular 5 mean login to third party website, issues with routing

Tags: angular, authentication, outlet, routerlink

In my header component I have have a Login button that logs me into a third party website. The app sc2 initialises in the Header Component with a callbackURL. In the header I am getting a LoginURL which is used to connect to sc2. To the loginURL I can add a state, which in my case is just a string with the id of the current page I am on, this returns in the params of the callback URL. The problem is that the Header never get's updated with the state, as the callback URL calls the main component (which is loaded in the router-outlet)
    The header itself is loaded above the main component. 
    I can't get the main component to reroute to the original component.
    Before I moved the button from the main component to the header component it all worked, now the state that is sent to the main component is not being updated to the last page, so I can't reroute it via the main component to the original.
page in use. I tried messageService and using localStorage, but it is as though the header Component never get's updated ontime. The callback URL is always to the main component. Can I talk directly to the Header Component?

**app.component**

```
  <app-header> </app-header>

  <router-outlet> </router-outlet>


  this.api = sc2.Initialize({
  app: 'someName.app',
  //  callbackURL: 'http://localhost/main/',
  callbackURL: this.callBackURL,
  accessToken: this.accessToken,
  scope: ['vote', 'comment']
 });


 this.loginUrl =  this.api.getLoginURL(this.state)
```

**page.component.ts**

```
     constructor() {
        this.newStateService.setState("page")
        this.newStateService.setCoinId("pageId")
        this.newStateService.changeMessageCoinId(this.coinId)
            const params = new HttpParams().set('_id', this.coinId);
       }
```

**Header component.ts**

```
  constructor() {

   this.newStateService.currentMessageState
   .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
  .subscribe(message => { 
  this.state = message
  })


 this.newStateService.currentMessageCoinId
  .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
  .subscribe(message => { 
  this.coinId= message
  })
 this.stateText = newStateService.getState();
 this.coinId = newStateService.getCoinId();  }
```

Comment: Improved code formatting

Answer (score 0):

zone issues you facing so you can use this method

```
import { ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(
private _applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {}

this.router.navigate(['/router']).then(() => {
    this._applicationRef.tick();
});
```